# How do you restart logstash on an AWS server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logstash, elastic-stack

This is a pretty basic question, but I coiuld nto for the life of me find a straight answer about it on google.

I have logstash/Kibana/Elastisearch installed and working on an AWS server.  Due to some complications, logstash stopped sending files to Kibana, and I wanted to restart it to see if it would fix the issue.  (This is on an Ubuntu 14.04.2).

All of the commands I looked up on google would not restart the service properly.  If I check the services running, logstash is on that list and has a -.

`restart logstash` gives the error `"Unknown job: logstash"`, and some of the others I found gave a similar kind of error.

What is the proper command to run in order to restart logstash?

Comment: Syntax error in logstash config file?

Comment: It was working a few days ago without any changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you installed `.deb` or `.rpm` package then you can restart using command

```
sudo service logstash restart
```

or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/logstash restart
```

or

```
sudo service logstash stop
sudo service logstash start
```

if you logstash creating problem to starting or stoping then you can start it manually also 
go to `/opt/logstash/bin` and run `logstash` script (`logstash.bat` for window)

```
cd /opt/logstash/bin
./logstash -f logstash-simple.conf
```

`logstash-simple.conf` is your logstash config file you can change it to any name

or 
if you downloaded .zip or any other compressed file then go that path and run same way.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer!